# Locally testing form handling with PHP

Tags: php, forms

I am creating an online order form for a wholesale nursery.  I am trying to test the PHP locally and have successfully set up WAMP.  When I test basic scripts, they run just fine but when I try using _POST to send data to variable from HTML input fields, nothing gets transferred to my PHP variables as noted when I try echoing them to a page.  Is there something I need to do to test _POST and _GET methods locally that I don't know about?

I tried testing my ability to do so using a simple example I found at W3 schools:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br>
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.

</body>
</html>
```

Like I said,  I used WAMP and both files are located in the wamp/www/ folder.

Comment: Without seeing the code for the form and the PHP script handing the form this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Try to wrap your entire PHP into one statement, then add this below your opening PHP tag `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`. Then you will need to name your submit button to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">` give that a try. Local server forms can be quite tricky at times.

Comment: I tested your code (as is) and it worked fine. Check your server settings. There's nothing more for me to do here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all all forms need a method (get, post) and an action (where to send the data) in the html.

`<form action='your/location.php' method='post'>`

`<input type='text' name='username'/>`

`<input type='submit' value='submit'/>`

`</form>`

All inputs must have a name attribute this is for referencing data in the php script

`<input type='text' name='username'/>`

In your/location.php you will receive an array with the data under the name:

`$_GET` or `$_POST` depending on your method set in the form tag.

To access specific data use `$_POST['username']` (replace username with any names set on any of the submitted form inputs)

To print out on the screen use
`echo $_POST['username'];`

Check if your file is under the extension `.php` and has the name `test`

If you get partial output and by partial i mean only the html part start you php server Apache or Nginx or whatever wamp uses, it might not start with all the functionality without specified to do so.

Make sure you open the page under localhost if you are testing it separately.

If for some reason you can't seem to get wamp to work try xampp which is similar and in my opinion better and never failed me.

Comment: *"First of all all forms need a method (get, post) and an action..."* The OP does: `<form action="test.php" method="post">` and then some so that's not the problem.

Comment: The OP's code checks out (as is). There's nothing more for us to do here. Cheers